# Rspec test :create method for a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, integration-testing

I'm trying to set up specs to properly run with my nested resource.

This is the test code I'm trying to properly set up

```
it "redirects to the created unit" do
    post :create, {:course_id => @course.id , :unit => valid_attributes}
    response.should redirect_to(course_unit_path(@course, Unit.last))
end
```

That essentially should try to create a nested resource "unit" for "course".
Unfortunatly I'm getting the following error on all POST DELETE and PUT tests

```
Failure/Error: post :create, {:course_id => @course.id , :unit => valid_attributes}
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `unit_url' for #<UnitsController:0x000000059f1000>
```

That makes sense since unit_url should be course_unit_url but it's RSpec calling it...

How can I make RSpec select the right named path?
For all GET tests I passed the :course_id by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
it "redirects to the created unit" do
  unit_id = "barry"
  Unit.any_instance.should_receive(:save).and_return(true)
  Unit.any_instance.stub(:id).and_return(unit_id)
  post :create, {:course_id => @course.to_param , :unit => valid_attributes}
  response.should redirect_to(course_unit_path(@course, unit_id))
end
```

I decided that the point of this test was not that it created a new model and redirected it, but simply that it redirects. I have another spec to ensure it creates a new model. Another benefit to this approach is that it doesn't touch the database so it should run a little faster.

I hope that helps.

**Edit:**

I also just noticed I have this in my `before :each` section which may be relevant:

```
Course.stub!(:find).and_return(@course)
```

**Edit again:**

In this case, there was code in the controller which was doing the offending call. As per comment below.

Comment: Hmm. It works for me. Does it still fail if you use 1 instead of "barry"? I suppose I'm also using the equivalent of course_unit_url instead of course_unit_path. Does that make any difference?

Comment: Yeah, it's still failing... please take a look at the whole spec [here](http://pastebin.com/sczZYEz6) if it may help. "login_admin" is a controller spec macro to login using devise.

Comment: Ah, I do have something extra in my `before :each` that I forgot.

Comment: Damn, I find it. I should post the whole traceback. It was telling that because inside the controller it was calling units_url :-/
I'm sorry about that but I'm new to RSpec and the whole BDD.
I'm going to accept your answer since it was really helpful.
If you can, please, add just a note reccomending also to check that it is not the controller itself to be calling that route, just to help future people having the same error.